# Whys there no module named numbers in my circuitpython raspberry pi pico?

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

So i was testing my TFT but when i uploaded the code

```
import board
import displayio
import terminalio
from adafruit_ili9341 import ILI9341

# Initialize ILI9341 display
spi = board.SPI()
tft_cs = board.D9
tft_dc = board.D10
display_bus = displayio.FourWire(spi, command=tft_dc, chip_select=tft_cs, reset=board.D6)
display = ILI9341(display_bus, width=320, height=240)

# Create a display group
group = displayio.Group(max_size=10)
display.show(group)

# Function to display text
def display_text(text, x, y, color):
    text_area = label.Label(terminalio.FONT, text=text, color=color, x=x, y=y)
    group.append(text_area)
    
# Clear the screen
display.fill(0)
display.show()

# Display text
display_text("Hello, CircuitPython!", 50, 100, 0xFFFF00)  # Yellow color
```

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/lib/adafruit_ili9341/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/lib/adafruit_ili9341/ILI9341.py", line 21, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'numbers'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Bcuz the "numbers" module is supposed to be installed since you flash the circuitpython firmware. I removed the lib folder because i needed more space.

I tried searching it in the library manager but it wasnt there.
I also tried reflashing but it just stayed as it was.

Answer (score 0):

The layout in the filesystem of your library does not match the *current* CircuitPython library. I can see https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ILI9341 which looks like what you have but that's not intended for use with CircuitPython and has a note about deprecation. I'm not familiar with it but I think it's an old library for the Raspberry Pi (not Pico).

The CircuitPython libraries can be downloaded from https://circuitpython.org/libraries - these tend to be small libraries designed to run on relatively low memory microcontrollers. If there's a Python 3 equivalent then they are likely to be cut-down versions. It looks like there are two libraries currently in the bundle that support this display type (note: `CircuitPython` is in the repository name):

- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ILI9341
- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RGB_Display

You mentioned a "library manager" - what's that refer to?

As a general tip, you can check the builtin modules by running `help("modules")` on CircuitPython REPL and the rest by looking in the library path, `/lib` is recommended place to put them but `sys.path` tells me `['', '/', '.frozen', '/lib']`.